# Why does createElement() doesn't work with "body" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, frontend

A while ago I've started to grasp a little bit of what JavaScript Is about (finally). Now I'm trying to make a video to help people that may have a hard time with It just like I had. If I'm teaching DOM, I really need to understand It deeply so I can make It easier for everyone else. I can't just put It out there that when you're creating an element, you can simply not use the word *body* In your code without any reasoning behind that.

If I try to change the background color with vanilla js, I would type It like this: `document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'darkgray'`.

If I try to create an h1 by typing: `document.createElement('h1')`, without the *body*, It works. If I try to create It by adding the word *body*: `document.body.createElement('h1')` It doesn't. Why Is that?

It sounds like a really silly question, but I couldn't find an answer to It.

Comment: createElement() is the function of document. So document.body.createElement('h1') is not work.

Comment: `createElement` creates an element. It does not add the element to the DOM yet, if that’s what you were expecting. Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model): there are DOM manipulation methods that add elements to the DOM. [`createElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) is a method on `Document.prototype` and `HTMLDocument.prototype`. `document.body` is neither a `Document` nor an `HTMLDocument`; it’s an `HTMLBodyElement`, and elements are not documents.

Answer (score 2):

Because `createElement` is a method of `document`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

If you want to add the element on the body maybe you have to look at `appendChild` like:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways of answering this.

The begging-the-question way is just: Because that's how the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) is defined. `createElement` is on the [`Document` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), not the various interfaces that `body` implements (`Node`, `Element`, `HTMLElement`, `HTMLBodyElement`, ...).

More fundamentally, though, documents control/know the kinds of elements that are valid for them, so it makes *sense* for `createElement` to be a method of `Document` rather than, say, `Node` or `HTMLBodyElement`. The `createElement` method doesn't really make sense for them — what would it mean for `body` to create, say, an `html` element? Or a `head` element? They can't be part of `body`, so it would be odd for `body` to create them.